# Converting read variables to lowercase in sh on ubuntu

Tags: bash, shell, sh, ubuntu-12.04, lowercase

I have the following situation:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Please enter a word:"
read foobar
```

The script is getting called with `sh script.sh` in the Ubuntu terminal.
Searching on the internet for solutions I found:

```
foobar=${foobar,,}
echo $foobar
```

The above approach does only work with `bash script.sh`
So I went on researching and found:

```
echo $foobar | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
```

Which does indeed work for both, `bash` and `sh`, but without the echo it does not work.
It also prints the read input two times instead of one like so:
Y
y

So how can I do this for `sh` without printing the read input twice?

Comment: Works perfectly for me. With dash (sh on ubuntu12.04) and bash

Comment: You have a `#!/bin/bash` shebang but want to call your script with `sh`?

Comment: @hek2mgl Calling the script with `sh` here gives me the error `bad substitution`, while calling the script with `bash` works.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Yes, I know it's weird. But I get the same result when calling the script with ./script.sh, after it's permissions are set to executable.

Comment: Another bash method: `declare -l foobar: read -p "Please enter a word:" foobar`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's probably because you didn't assign the translated output to a variable yet. Also I suggest quoting your variables around doublequotes to prevent word splitting and pathname expansion.

```
foobar=$(echo "$foobar" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
```

If you're using `case` and you just need to check if an input is `y` or `Y` either way you can use a glob pattern like this. There's no need to transliterate it to lowercase form.

```
case $foobar in
[yY])
    echo "User said yes."
    ;;
*)
    echo "User said no."
    ;;
esac
```

Also you can somehow suppress showing user input by using -s:

```
read -s foobar
```

As a whole to make your code work well in both `bash` and `sh` you should already remove the part which is bash specific:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Please enter a word:"
read -s foobar
foobar=$(echo "$foobar" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
echo "$foobar"
```

And if it's just about showing the smaller form, you can skip the assignment. But don't use another echo along with it:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Please enter a word:"
read -s foobar
echo "$foobar" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
```

Another alternative form from `case`. This is meant to be POSIX compatible.

```
if [ "$foobar" = y ] || [ "$foobar" = Y ]; then
    echo "User said yes."
else
    echo "User said no."
fi
```

In bash it could be simply like this. It would work even in earlier versions that doesn't support `${parameter,,}` feature.

```
if [[ $foobar == [yY] ]]; then
    echo "User said yes."
else
    echo "User said no."
fi
```

Comment: This prints the input twice.

Comment: Alright, the case solution works! Is there something similar in an if else situation?

Comment: Ok, I got it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use `-r` option to save the input into REPLY variable and then pipe it to `tr` command.

```bash
read -r -p "Enter something: "; echo "${REPLY}" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
```

Output:

```
Enter something: HeLLo, WOrlD!
hello, world!
```

Do you want to save it in a variable? It's simple, just use command substitution:

```bash
foobar=$(read -r -p "Enter something: "; echo "${REPLY}" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
```

Also, here is another style that is a little simpler (maybe):

```bash
read -p "Enter something: " text && tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' <<< "${text}"
```